# La couleur impossible

Tags: sens, adjectifs

L’article [*impossible*](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/impossible) au TLFi mentionne comme acception possible :

> Vx. Nom d'une couleur à la mode à la fin du XVIII<sup>e</sup> siècle.

Pour illustrer cette acception, on cite Gérard de Nerval, dont voici un extrait plus long :

> Le 7 du mois d’août fut le grand jour. La scène se passa dans une vaste maison, rue Verte-Saint-Honoré. On s’y rendit à onze heures. En entrant dans la première salle, chaque femme était obligée de quitter sa bouffante, ses soutiens, son corps, son faux chignon, et de vêtir une lévite blanche avec une ceinture de couleur. Il y en avait six en noir, six en bleu, six en coquelicot, six en violet, six en couleur de rose, **six en impossible.** On leur remit à chacune un grand voile qu’elles placèrent en sautoir de gauche à droite.

Je n’ai pas trouvé trace de cette couleur dans mes dictionnaires, et les recherches sur internet me guident invariablement dans des directions inappropriées : couleurs interdites *(soient des variations dont Cubitus nous offre un bel échantillon ci-dessous)*, problèmes d’impression, photographie, assemblages de couleurs dont le final est difficile à définir, etc.

[image]

Quelqu’un saurait-il indiquer quelle était la nature de cette couleur qui inspirait les tailleurs et les élégants à la fin du XVIII<sup>e</sup> ?

Answer (score 3):

On ne sait pas exactement : on émet l'hypothèse, en se fondant sur une seule source et par généralisation, qu'en ce qui a trait à la couleur des cheveux ce pourrait être une couleur de type *blond vénitien* soit « un blond mélangé d'une teinte de roux plus ou moins prononcée, ce qui donne une coiffure avec des nuances dorées et cuivrées » ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blond_v%C3%A9nitien)) ou un « blond rutilant, tirant sur le roux, que les femmes de Venise obtenaient par un traitement spécial » ([TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/v%C3%A9nitien)). On ne sait pas comment ça s'appliquerait à la *ceinture*, si le jaune ou les reflets (dorés/cuivrés) l'emporterait...

---

Certaines [éditions](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22en%20impossible%22%20-souvent%20-souuent%20couleur) présentent l'extrait en question avec entre parenthèses *couleur de [fantaisie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fantaisie)*, termes « souvent inventés dans le domaine de la mode, dont seuls les initiés peuvent imaginer la teinte exacte, comme *puce* ou *cuisse de nymphe*, dont les noms peuvent être purement commémoratifs, comme *céladon* ou *magenta* » ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noms_et_adjectifs_de_couleur)). Le *DHLF* connaît l'emploi mais ne précise pas de quelle couleur il s'agirait :

> Deux acceptions hyperboliques concrètes concernent *les Impossibles*
>   désignant les femmes légèrement vêtues de l'époque Directoire et
>   *l'impossible* une couleur à la mode à fin du XVIII<sup>e</sup> (1852) ; elles sont rapidement sorties de l'usage.
>
> [ *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* (sup. Rey, ed.
>   Robert, 2011) ]

On sait par élimination vu l'extrait qu'il ne s'agit ni du noir, bleu, coquelicot, violet ou rose. En guise d'introduction on a aussi consulté un [article](https://www.paris-pittoresque.com/costumes/1.htm) bien illustré traitant des costumes à l'époque [Directoire](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directoire) (1795-1799) s'appuyant sur une œuvre dont on a analysé toutes les phrases contenant le mot *impossible* etc. Une seule semblait pertinente, au sujet de la mode sous le [Second Empire](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Empire) (1852-1870):

> L'industrie ne se lassait point, le génie parisien avait quelquefois
>   du bon goût, même dans le mauvais ton ; — on vit des boucles d'oreilles
>   *aquarium*, des chaînes d'or *Benoîton*, qui formaient gourmette sous le menton on chaussa le cuir de Russie, on l'employa en ceintures,
>   avec boucles de métal ; on se surchargea de chaînettes et de breloques
>   et l'on campa sur les chevelures jaune, acajou, tomate, et sur toutes
>   les nuances impossibles à la mode, qui n'étaient que les outrances du
>   blond vénitien, — des chapeaux Trianon, Watteau, Lamhalle et Marie
>   Antoinette.
>
> [ Monument esthématique du XIXe siècle : les modes de Paris,
>   variations du goût et de l'esthétique de la femme, 1797-1897, (1898),
>   [Octave Uzanne](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octave_Uzanne), [p. 176](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k204703s/f254.item.r=impossible) ]

On a tenté de trouver rapidement un [nuancier](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuancier) ancien, sans succès, et on a consulté un [traité](https://books.google.com/books?id=lHQUAAAAQAAJ&dq=%22couleurs%20de%20fantaisie%22&pg=PA287#v=onepage&q=%22couleurs%20de%20fantaisie%22&f=false) du 19<sup>e</sup> sur l'impression des tissus pour donner le ton. Mais on pense que cet emploi d'*impossible*, sans référer â la couleur comme telle, est hyperbolique pour *invraisemblable, extravagant* ([TLFi](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/impossible), comme avec *chapeau* etc. ; ou rare) et pourrait englober la couleur *impossible* au sens strict, l'ensemble étant assimilé aux *[outrances](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/outrance)* ([!](https://www.littre.org/definition/outrance)) [aux « exagérations »] *du blond vénitien* en contexte capillaire. Donc oui c'est tiré par les cheveux, *impossible*...

Comment: Merci pour cette première piste et pour cet intéressant document sur la femme et l'amour après la Terreur. Je laisse ouvert, si par hasard quelqu'un trouvait davantage, mais j'apprécie votre effort et admire votre capacité à traquer une information bien cachée.

Comment: @Feelew Merci, avec plaisir ! Avez-vous pensé poser la Q. sur _Graphic Design SE_ ? J'ai un compte là-dessus, faut réviser leurs règles pour voir, mais ils ont peut-être accès à des types de documents auxquels on n'a pas accès, des nuanciers historiques ou des outils professionnels sur la couleur dont le cadre dépasserait peut-être celui de la langue ?

Comment: À investiguer, certainement. Merci!